# Comparison between dplyr::do / purrr::map, what advantages?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, broom

When using [`broom`](http://varianceexplained.org/r/broom-intro/) I was used to combine `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::do` to perform actions on grouped data thanks to @drob.
For example, fitting a linear model to cars depending on their gear system:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("broom")

# using do()
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: am [2]

#     am        term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
#   (dbl)       (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)        (dbl)
# 1     0 (Intercept) 31.416055 2.9467213 10.661360 6.007748e-09
# 2     0          wt -3.785908 0.7665567 -4.938848 1.245595e-04
# 3     1 (Intercept) 46.294478 3.1198212 14.838824 1.276849e-08
# 4     1          wt -9.084268 1.2565727 -7.229401 1.687904e-05
```

After reading the recent post from @hadley about [`tidyr v0.4.1`](http://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/)
I discovered that the same thing could be achieved using `nest()` and `purrr::map()`

Same example as before:

```
by_am <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = purrr::map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)))

by_am %>%
  unnest(model %>% purrr::map(tidy))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]

#      am        term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
#   (dbl)       (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)        (dbl)
# 1     1 (Intercept) 46.294478 3.1198212 14.838824 1.276849e-08
# 2     1          wt -9.084268 1.2565727 -7.229401 1.687904e-05
# 3     0 (Intercept) 31.416055 2.9467213 10.661360 6.007748e-09
# 4     0          wt -3.785908 0.7665567 -4.938848 1.245595e-04
```

The ordering changed, but results are the same.

Given both largely address the same use case, I am wondering whether are both approaches going to be supported going forward.  Will method become the canonical `tidyverse` way? 
If one is not considered canonical, what use case(s) require that both approaches continues to be supported?

From my short experience:

- **do**

  - progress bar, nice when many models are computed.
  - @Axeman comment: can be parallelized using `multidplyr`
  - smaller object, but need to re-run if we want `broom::glance` fx.
- **map**

  - data, subsets and models are kept within one `tbl_df`
  - easy to extract another component of models, even if `unnest()` takes a bit of time.

If you have some insights / remarks, will be happy to have some feedback.

Comment: One advantage of `dplyr::do` is that it can be parallelized with the `multidplyr` package/

Comment: Both approaches benefit from parallelisation with multidplyr. I think the only real advantage is the progress bar for do, but purrr will also get progress bars at some point.

Comment: @hadley thanks! Good to know. I really like the progress bar in do. Thanks again for developing such nice tools

Comment: see a great presentation with much more details on purrr functionalities: http://ijlyttle.github.io/isugg_purrr/presentation.html#%281%29  by Ian Lytte. Especially from slide #20

Comment: according to @hadley, the approach dplyr::do() is going to be deprecated in favor of purrr https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/719542847045636096