# purrr map a t.test onto a split df

Tags: r, purrr

I'm new to purrr, [Hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley)'s promising functional programming [R library](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/). I'm trying to take a grouped and split dataframe and run a t-test on a variable. An example using a sample dataset might look like this.

```
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~ t.test(.$`4`$mpg, .$`6`$mpg))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error in var(x) : 'x' is NULL
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Am I just misunderstanding how `map` works? Or is there a better way to think about this?

Comment: One thing I notices is that the examples in the `map` docs show `map` operating on each list item from `split` separately, but your example is trying to operate between list items.

Comment: Yes, very true. Any idea if there is an easy way to operate between list items?

Comment: I am not sure how you would get it to work wity `map` but you could capture the results up to `split` then use `lapply` on that result.

Comment: I was thinking something like the following.  If you capture the results up to `split` in `mtcars_split` then you could do something like `lapply(names(mtcars_split)[2:length(mtcars_split)], function(x) { t.test(mtcars_split[['4']]$mpg, mtcars_split[[x]]$mpg) })`.  I suspect there is a cleaner (i.e. more readable) way to do this though.

Comment: this might be helpful additional reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505187/comparison-between-dplyrdo-purrrmap-what-advantages

Comment: Why is it being called "Hadley's" (with a link no less) when its creator  _and_ maintainer was/is Lionel Henry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Especially when dealing with pipes that require multiple inputs (we don't have Haskell's Arrows here), I find it easier to reason by types/signatures first, then encapsulate logic in functions (which you can unit test), then write a concise chain.

In this case you want to compare all possible pairs of vectors, so I would set a goal of writing a function that takes a pair (i.e. a list of 2) of vectors and returns the 2-way t.test of them.

Once you've done this, you just need some glue. So the plan is:

1. Write function that takes a list of vectors and performs the 2-way t-test.
2. Write a function/pipe that fetches the vectors from mtcars (easy).
3. Map the above over the list of pairs.

It's important to have this plan before writing any code. Things are somehow obfuscated by the fact that R is not strongly typed, but this way you reason about "types" first, implementation second.

#### Step 1

t.test takes dots, so we use `purrr:lift` to have it take a list. Since we don't want to match on the names of the elements of the list, we use `.unnamed = TRUE`. Also we make it extra clear we're using the `t.test` function with arity of 2 (though this extra step is not needed for the code to work).

```
t.test2 <- function(x, y) t.test(x, y)
liftedTT <- lift(t.test2, .unnamed = TRUE)
```

#### Step 2

Wrap the function we got in step 1 into a functional chain that takes a simple pair (here I use indexes, it should be easy to use cyl factor levels, but I don't have time to figure it out).

```
doTT <- function(pair) {
  mtcars %>%
    split(as.character(.$cyl)) %>%
    map(~ select(., mpg)) %>% 
    extract(pair) %>% 
    liftedTT %>% 
    broom::tidy
}
```

#### Step 3

Now that we have all our lego pieces ready, composition is trivial.

```
1:length(unique(mtcars$cyl)) %>% 
  combn(2) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  as.list %>% 
  map(~ doTT(.))

$V1
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic      p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
1 6.920779  26.66364  19.74286  4.719059 0.0004048495  12.95598 3.751376  10.09018

$V2
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic      p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
1 11.56364  26.66364      15.1  7.596664 1.641348e-06  14.96675 8.318518  14.80876

$V3
  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic      p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
1 4.642857  19.74286      15.1  5.291135 4.540355e-05  18.50248 2.802925  6.482789
```

---

There's quite a bit here to clean up, mainly using factor levels and preserving them in the output (and not using globals in the second function) but I think the core of what you wanted is here. The trick not to get lost, in my experience, is to work from the inside out.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. `Error in UseMethod("extract_") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "list"`. i'm using packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0        purrr_0.2.2        readr_1.0.0        tidyr_0.6.0       
[5] tibble_1.2         ggplot2_2.1.0.9001 tidyverse_1.0.0

Answer (score 11):

I don't fully understand the expected result, but this might be a starting point for an answer.  `map()` from `purrr` uses `.x` in the formula argument.

Here is one way to accomplish what I think you are trying to do with just `purrr`.

```
mtcars %>%
  split(as.character(.$cyl)) %>%
  map(~t.test(.x$mpg))
```

But, `purrr::by_slice()` pairs nicely with `dplyr::group_by()`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>%
  by_slice(~ t.test(.x$mpg))
```

Or, you could skip `purrr` entirely using `dplyr:::summarise()`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>%
  summarise(t_test = data_frame(t.test(.$mpg)))
```

If the nested `data.frame` is confusing, `broom` can help us get an easy `data.frame` summary of the results.

`purrr` + `broom` + `tidyr`

```
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>%
  by_slice(~tidy(t.test(.x$mpg))) %>%
  unnest()
```

`dplyr` + `broom`

```
library(broom)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>%
  do(tidy(t.test(.$mpg)))
```

**Edited to include response to comment**

With pipes, we can get carried away quite quickly.  I think Walt did a nice job in his answer, but I wanted to make sure that I provided a `purrr`-ty answer.  I hope the use of `pipeR` is not overly confusing.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(pipeR)

mtcars %>>%
  (split(.,.$cyl)) %>>%
  (split_cyl~
    names(split_cyl) %>>%
     (
       cross_d(
         list(against=.,tested=.),
         .filter = `==`
       )
     ) %>>%
     by_row(
       ~tidy(t.test(split_cyl[[.x$tested]]$mpg,split_cyl[[.x$against]]$mpg))
     )
  ) %>>%
  unnest()
```

Comment: This is great, thanks very much! I didn't know about that dplyr::data_frame usage. That'll come in handy

Comment: The broom updates are very helpful!

A quick clarification: this result set shows a `t.test` for each slice or group. How can I compare one group to another. Something like `t.test(4$mpg, 6$mpg)`?

Comment: The **skip purrr entirely using dplyr:::summarise()** does not work: `Erreur : Variables must be length 1 or 9. Problem variables: 'as.character(cyl)'`; `summarise` do not like the returned data frames. I like the purrr + dplyr solution :)

Comment: `by_slice` and `by_row` in `purrr` are now deprecated. So the workable solutions now is the usage of `dplyr` + `broom` to summarize the grouped statistics.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the two sample t-tests, you have to create the combinations of the numbers of cylinders. I don't see that you can create the combinations using `purrr` functions.  However a way which uses only `purrr` and base R functions is

```
library(purrr)
t_test2 <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>%
          transpose() %>%
          .[["mpg"]] %>%
          (function(x) combn(names(x), m=2, function(y) t.test(flatten_dbl(x[y[1]]), flatten_dbl(x[y[2]])) , simplify=FALSE))
```

although this does seem a bit contrived.

A similar approach which uses only base R functions with chaining is

```
t_test <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>%
                          (function(x) combn(names(x), m=2, function(y) x[y], simplify=FALSE)) %>%
                           lapply( function(x) t.test(x[[1]]$mpg, x[[2]]$mpg))
```