# How to preform shapiro test with group by function

Tags: r, dplyr, normal-distribution

```
Type <- c("Bark", "Redwood", "Oak")
size <- c(10,15,13)
width <- c(3,4,5)
Ratio <- size/width
df <- data.frame(Type, size, width, Ratio)
mutate(df, ratio_log = log10(Ratio))
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% shapiro.test(ratio_log)
```

> Error in shapiro.test(., ratio_log) : unused argument (ratio_log)

I am attempting to apply the Shapiro test for all of the types, e.g, bark, redwood, oak. not all the ratios combined. I have a larger data set that consists of more ratios.

Comment: You need a minimum sample size between 3 and 5000 for shapiro.test. Can you give an example of a larger dataframe with all ratios?

Comment: Your error is generated by the fact that you are not adding storing `ratio_log` into your `df`. The following code is a solution: `df <- data.frame(Type, size, width, Ratio) %>%
mutate(ratio_log = log10(Ratio))`. For the Shapiro Test please add a suitable example

Answer (score 7):

You need tidyverse for purrr and dplyr at least.

And I made more samples in the example since you need a vector for `shapiro.test` and not a single ratio. So here is 100 samples from a normal, a binomial and a uniform distribution.

```
library(tidyverse)

Type <- c("Bark", "Redwood", "Oak")
size <- c(10,15,13)
width <- c(3,4,5)
Ratio <- c(rnorm(100),
           rbinom(100, size = 2, prob = 0.2),
           runif(100))
```

Put these in a data.frame

```
# Need minimum sample size for shapiro test
df <- data.frame(Type = rep(Type, each = 100),
                 Size = rep(size, each = 100),
                 width = rep(size, each = 100),
                 Ratio)
```

Then you can use the ratio_log, in this case I took the liberty of just using the same ratio. You can group by `Type` and use `nest` to nest a data.frame of the data per group.

```
df %>%
  mutate(ratio_log = Ratio) %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(N_Samples = n()) %>%
  nest()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Type    data              
  <fct>   <list>            
1 Bark    <tibble [100 x 5]>
2 Redwood <tibble [100 x 5]>
3 Oak     <tibble [100 x 5]>
```

You can then use the `map` function together with `mutate` to basically do `lapply` applied to the nested data.frames (or tibbles, same thing essentially here.) To each data.frame per group we apply the `shapiro.test` function to the values in the `ratio_log` column.

```
# Use purrr::nest and purrr::map to do shapiro tests per group
df.shapiro <- df %>%
  mutate(ratio_log = Ratio) %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(N_Samples = n()) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(Shapiro = map(data, ~ shapiro.test(.x$ratio_log)))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Type    data               Shapiro    
  <fct>   <list>             <list>     
1 Bark    <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>
2 Redwood <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>
3 Oak     <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>
```

Now you have nested `shapiro.test` results, applied to each group.

To get the relevant parameters you can use `glance` from the `broom` package. Then `unnest` the result from the `glance` function.

```
# Use broom::glance and purrr::unnest to get all relevant statistics
library(broom)
df.shapiro.glance <- df.shapiro %>%
  mutate(glance_shapiro = Shapiro %>% map(glance)) %>%
  unnest(glance_shapiro)

 Type    data               Shapiro     statistic  p.value method                     
  <fct>   <list>             <list>          <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>                      
1 Bark    <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>     0.967 1.30e- 2 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
2 Redwood <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>     0.638 2.45e-14 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
3 Oak     <tibble [100 x 5]> <S3: htest>     0.937 1.31e- 4 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

Comment: Thanks Lodewic, this was exactly the solution I needed and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

Type <- c("Bark", "Redwood", "Oak")
size <- c(10,15,13)
width <- c(3,4,5)
Ratio <- size/width
df <- data.frame(Type, size, width, Ratio)

df %>% 
  mutate(ratio_log = log10(Ratio)) %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(results = data_frame(shapiro.test(.$ratio_log)))
```

You an also see other solutions here: [purrr map a t.test onto a split df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558766/purrr-map-a-t-test-onto-a-split-df)