# advice on Usage of dplyr:: do vs purrr: map, tidy::nest, for predictions

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I just came across the the purrr package and I think this would help me out a bit in terms of what I want to do - I just can't put it together.

I think this is going to be along post but goes over a common use case I think many others run into so hopefully this is of use to them as well.

This is what I'm aiming for:

1. From one big dataset run multiple models on each of the different subgroups.
2. Have these models readily available so I can examine - for coeffients, accuracy, etc.
3. From this saved model list for each of the different groupings, be able to apply the corresponding model to the corresponding test-set group.

> ```
> grouping_vals = c("cyl", "vs")
>
> library(purrr)
> library(dplyr)
> set.seed(1)
> train=mtcars
> noise = sample(1:5,32, replace=TRUE) 
> test = mtcars %>% mutate( hp = hp * noise) # just so dataset isn't identical
>
>
> models = train %>% 
> group_by_(grouping_vals) %>%
> do(linear_model1 = lm(mpg ~hp, data=.),
>    linear_model2 = lm(mpg ~., data=.)
> )
> ```

1. I've gotten this far but I don't know how to 'map' the corresponding models to the "**test**"  dataset for the corresponding grouped values.
2. Now I also might be trying to get the residuals from the training of the linear_model1 or linear_model2 with the training-data for the corresponding groups.

models$linear_model1[[2]]$residuals will show me the residuals for the 2nd grouping of model1.  I just don't know how move say all of models$linear_model1 $residuals over to the train dataset.

My understanding is that tidyr's nest() function is doing the same thing that occurs when I create my do() create of the models.

```
   models_with_nest =  train %>% 
     group_by_(grouping_vals) %>%
                   nest() %>%
     mutate( linear_model2 = purrr::map(data, ~lm(mpg~., data=.)),
             linear_model1 = purrr::map(data, ~lm(mpg~ hp+disp, data=.))
     )
```

Again just look for a way to easily be able to 'map' these residuals/training predictions to the training dataset and apply then apply the corresponding model to an unseen   test dataset like the one I created above.

I hope this isn't confusing since I see a lot of promise here I just can't figure out how to put it together.

I figure this is a task that a ton of people would like to be able to do in this more 'automated' way but instead is something that people do very slowly and step by step.

Comment: Package broom's `augment` is useful for adding the residuals to the dataset used to fit the model.  For making predictions with the test dataset you can use `predict` in `map`, using the `newdata` argument. If you haven't already seen it, you might also be interested in this [talk by Hadley Wickham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg) that goes through an example of fitting many models with dplyr/tidyr/purrr/broom.

Comment: Yes I thought of Broom but most of the models I run don't seem to comply with it - this was a simple example but I was thinking it would be run using Neural Networks, SVM, Random Forest, etc

Comment: Have you read http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html?

Answer (score 3):

I'm really interested in finding out differences between the `do` and the `nest, map` approaches. Maybe people have tried both and they can comment in which is faster when dealing with much bigger datasets, or much more models.

So far I've been using the `do` approach as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

# reproducible results
set.seed(47)

# shuffle / randomise rows
mtcars2 = mtcars %>% sample_frac(1)

# split train / test
mtcars_train = mtcars2[1:20,]
mtcars_test = mtcars2[21:32,]

# for each cyl group create subsets and fit the models of interest using do
dt_models = mtcars_train %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(model1 = lm(disp ~ hp, data = .),
     model2 = lm(disp ~ mpg, data = .)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  print()

# reshape model dataset (for easier use later)
dt_models = dt_models %>% gather("name","model", -cyl) %>% print()

# function to pick model and predict corresponding data (row)
GetModelAndPredict = function(input_cyl, model_name, dd){

  m = (dt_models %>% filter(cyl==input_cyl & name==model_name))$model[[1]]

  predict.lm(m, newdata=dd)

}

# predict each row using the corresponding model
mtcars_test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(.,
                pred1 = GetModelAndPredict(.$cyl, "model1", .),
                pred2 = GetModelAndPredict(.$cyl, "model2", .))) %>%
  ungroup


# # A tibble: 12 × 13
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     pred1     pred2
# *  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1 103.11501 115.24903
# 2   17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3 356.19839 316.20091
# 3   18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1 200.10912 151.56750
# 4   21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4 195.69767 198.89904
# 5   32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1  87.99347  77.54320
# 6   26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2 101.99490 102.68042
# 7   15.8     8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4 365.97745 339.57501
# 8   24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2  85.75324 108.96473
# 9   27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1  87.99347  97.57442
# 10  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1  87.43341  71.65166
# 11  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2 104.23513 115.24903
# 12  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2 355.61630 294.38507
```

But I found really interesting the `nest, map` approach as well:

```
library(tidyverse)

# reproducible results
set.seed(47)

# shuffle / randomise rows
mtcars2 = mtcars %>% sample_frac(1)

# split train / test
mtcars_train = mtcars2[1:20,]
mtcars_test = mtcars2[21:32,]

# for each cyl group create subsets and fit the models of interest using map
dt_models = mtcars_train %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>%
  mutate(model1 = map(data, ~lm(disp ~ hp, data = .)),
         model2 = map(data, ~lm(disp ~ mpg, data = .))) %>%
  rename(data_train = data) %>%
  print()

# join test data to be able to predict them
dt_models_and_test_data = mtcars_test %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>%
  inner_join(dt_models, by = "cyl") %>%
  rename(data_test = data) %>%
  print()

# predict test data using map2
dt_preds = dt_models_and_test_data %>%
  mutate(pred1 = map2(model1, data_test, predict.lm),
         pred2 = map2(model2, data_test, predict.lm)) %>%
  print()

# go back to a reasonable data frame using unnest on columns of interest
dt_preds_upd = dt_preds %>%
  unnest(data_test,pred1,pred2) %>%
  print()


# # A tibble: 12 × 13
#      cyl     pred1     pred2   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      4 103.11501 115.24903  22.8 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# 2      4  87.99347  77.54320  32.4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
# 3      4 101.99490 102.68042  26.0 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2
# 4      4  85.75324 108.96473  24.4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2
# 5      4  87.99347  97.57442  27.3  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1
# 6      4  87.43341  71.65166  33.9  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
# 7      4 104.23513 115.24903  22.8 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2
# 8      8 356.19839 316.20091  17.3 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
# 9      8 365.97745 339.57501  15.8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4
# 10     8 355.61630 294.38507  18.7 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
# 11     6 200.10912 151.56750  18.1 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
# 12     6 195.69767 198.89904  21.0 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
```

Comment: see some comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505187/comparison-between-dplyrdo-purrrmap-what-advantages

Comment: As @aurelien notes its relevance, please vote to reopen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505187/comparison-between-dplyrdo-purrrmap-what-advantages

Comment: @AntoniosK reply should be marked as a solution. Great work!