# For loop regression estimations (ECM model)

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I am estimating a time series Error Correction Model on my data (with package 'ecm'). In below code you can see that I specify the short and long term variables with xeq and xtr.

These variables are independent variables and estimate on the dependent variable: Sales.

In this case, it is a pooled model but I want to estimate this  model unit by unit (so separate for every brand). Since my dataset is rather large and consists of 360 product categories, each having 3 brands (brand 2, brand 3 and brand 4).

```
xeq <- DatasetThesisSynergyClean[c('lnPrice', 'lnAdvertising', 'lnDisplay', 'IntrayearCycles', 'lnCompetitorPrices', 'lnCompADV', 'lnCompDISP' , 'ADVxDISP', 'ADVxCYC', 'DISPxCYC', 'ADVxDISPxCYC')]     
xtr <- DatasetThesisSynergyClean[c('lnPrice', 'lnAdvertising', 'lnDisplay', 'IntrayearCycles', 'lnCompetitorPrices', 'lnCompADV', 'lnCompDISP', 'ADVxDISP',  'ADVxCYC', 'DISPxCYC', 'ADVxDISPxCYC')]     
model11 <- ecm(DatasetThesisSynergyClean$lnSales, xeq, xtr, includeIntercept=TRUE)
summary(model11)
```

What I want is to generate an output for every brand of every category. To give you glimpse of my data, please run this code:

```
structure(list(Week = 7:17, Category = c("2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), Brand = c("3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), Display = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Sales = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 13.440948, 40.097397, 
32.01384, 382.169189, 2830.748779, 4524.460938, 1053.590576), 
    Price = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 5.949999, 5.95, 5.950003, 4.87759, 
    3.787015, 3.205987, 4.898724), Distribution = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1.394019, 1.386989, 1.621416, 8.209759, 8.552915, 9.692097, 
    9.445554), Advertising = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), lnSales = c(11.4945151554497, 11.633214247508, 11.5862944141137, 
    11.5412559646132, 11.4811122484454, 11.4775106999991, 11.6333660772506, 
    11.4859819773102, 11.5232680456161, 11.5572670584292, 11.5303686934256
    ), IntrayearCycles = c(4.15446534315765, 3.62757053512638, 
    2.92387946552647, 2.14946414386239, 1.40455011205262, 0.768856938870769, 
    0.291497141953598, -0.0131078404184544, -0.162984144025091, 
    -0.200882782749248, -0.182877633924882), `Competitor Advertising` = c(10584.87063, 
    224846.3243, 90657.72553, 0, 0, 0, 2396.54212, 0, 0, 0, 40343.49444
    ), `Competitor Display` = c(0.385629, 2.108133, 2.515806, 
    4.918288, 3.81749, 3.035847, 2.463194, 3.242594, 1.850399, 
    1.751096, 1.337943), `Competitor Prices` = c(5.30989, 5.372752, 
    5.3717245, 5.3295525, 5.298393, 5.319466, 5.1958415, 5.2941095, 
    5.296757, 5.294059, 5.273578), ZeroSales = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Week", "Category", "Brand", 
"Display", "Sales", "Price", "Distribution", "Advertising", "lnSales", 
"IntrayearCycles", "Competitor Advertising", "Competitor Display", 
"Competitor Prices", "ZeroSales"), row.names = 1255:1265, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, I have all the categories and brands stored in rows. To get an estimation on every single brand I want to write a for loop, but I don't really know how to specify the right category and brand in order to save this output separately.

Eventually want to store the coefficients, std. error, t-values and p-values, of all brands in 4 separate dataframes. But first I need to obtain the output, can you guys help me out?

Comment: There's an alternative way to build a model for each brand using `dplyr`, `purrr` packages. There many posts online that have to do with linear regression models. but you should be able to adjust it to your case. See some info here https://www.r-bloggers.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups/ and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621556/advice-on-usage-of-dplyr-do-vs-purrr-map-tidynest-for-predictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` like this:

```
f <- function(.) {
  xeq <- as.data.frame(select(., lnPrice, lnAdvertising, lnDisplay, IntrayearCycles, lnCompetitorPrices, lnCompADV, lnCompDISP, ADVxDISP, ADVxCYC, DISPxCYC, ADVxDISPxCYC))
  xtr <- as.data.frame(select(., lnPrice, lnAdvertising, lnDisplay, IntrayearCycles, lnCompetitorPrices, lnCompADV, lnCompDISP, ADVxDISP,  ADVxCYC, DISPxCYC, ADVxDISPxCYC))
  print(xeq)
  print(xtr)
  summary(ecm(.$lnSales, xeq, xtr, includeIntercept = TRUE))
}


Models <- DatasetThesisSynergyClean %>% 
  group_by(Category, Brand) %>% 
  do(Model = f(.))


Models$Category
[1] "2" "3"
Models$Brand
[1] "3" "3"
Models$Model
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = dy ~ ., data = x)
# ... and so on
```

You end up with a list of 3 items (the categories, brands and model summary objects) and length equal to unique category/brand combinations. Could not try it properly, since I do not have the complete data. Model summary for Category 3, Brand 3:

```
Models$Model[[which(Models$Category == 3 & Models$Brand == 3)]]
```

**Update:**

If you want standalone object for each model you can give them corresponding names and use `list2env()`:

```
names(Models$Model) <- paste0("C", Models$Category, "B", Models$Brand)
list2env(Models$Model, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This seems to work! I can see the DF 'models' and when I run the last three lines I see all the output showing up in the console. I only do not get how I should obtain the model output for one specific category&brand.

Comment: Well `Models$Model[[1]]` corresponds to Cat 2, Brand 3 for example... `Models$Category[1]` and `Models$Brand[1]`

Comment: So you could do this: `Models$Model[[which(Models$Category == 3 & Models$Brand == 3)]]`

Comment: Ah of course. The weird thing is that in my estimations ouptut, there are also variables containing NA's. That is weird, since my dataset does not contain any NA's at all.

Comment: Remove those variable that are zero constants. This will only prettify the summary output. The coefficients of the other variables wont change.

Comment: Ah, I see. I tackled the -inf problem beforehand. It is sometimes indeed that variables are 0, so there is nothing to make an estimation on since there is no effect. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: My dataset contains many zero's since it is rather big, so removing these would be a massive job, right? Because then I need to remove the whole brand, and so I lose good data as well.

Comment: I do not know your data. I do not know how many observations you have for each cat/brand combination. Maybe other data transformations help.

Comment: Almost 200.000 observations, haha. But, do you perhaps know how I could sum the RSS of ALL model outputs. I need to do a chow test for pooling or not. I think this works in a for loop as well? By first saving the RSS for every model and then summing it up. I know I opbtain these values with an Anova, but how do I obtain them for all of them?

Comment: Well I am not here to write your Bachelor thesis (?) ;) you have all the RSS in the Models object already. Use `lapply()` on that list to extract/do something.

Comment: Of course not! I'm not that experienced in R and they expect a bit too much from me in my Master's Thesis. It gives me errors in specifying the specific output for a model.. hopefully I find a solution.

Comment: One remaining question, I got the outputs in the console by calling them with [ .. ].  Is there also a way to save all these outputs separately?

Comment: Yes of course. See my update. Oh, notice that you can close questions by accepting an answer that is satisfying (concerning all your questions).

Comment: Ah, that works. Perfect! I know need to extract all residuals (RSS actually), p-values, coefficients and t-values for these dataframes. Do you know how to call these from the dataframes all together?

Comment: I need to export all my regression outputs into a new dataframe and I want to stack these in rows per variable. See my new post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891753/exporting-lm-summary-output-to-dataframe-including-na). Due to the NA's I cannot export all outputs in the same format. I found a way that in your LM code, you an include singular.ok = true to include the NA's (singularities) in the regressions. The weird thing is also that when I want summary output, I need print() instead of summary(). Can you help me with solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at some of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) packages, and consider using a vectorised approach combining `split(df, list(df$Category, df$Group))` and purrr's `map()` function to apply a function to each of your smaller datasets. The code would be something like this:

```
df %>% 
  split(f = list(.$Category, .$Brand)) %>% 
  map(a_function_for_each_group) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

I hope i have understood your question correctly.

Comment: I could apply this, but how should I proceed further then?

Comment: It is difficult to suggest a way to proceed without knowing the structure and content of the `a_function_for_each_group` output.